# jQuery.proxy vs. underscore.bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

In the context of using methods as event handlers (i.e. `$(...).on('something', myObject.handleSomething)`). I discovered the relatively large performance difference between $.proxy and _.bind (http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy/27) and looked at their implementation.

jQuery (http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=proxy) ends up returning:

```
args = core_slice.call(arguments, 2);
proxy = function () {
    return fn.apply(context || this, args.concat(core_slice.call(arguments)));
};
```

while underscore (http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-60) ends up returning (ctor is `var ctor = function(){};`):

```
args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
return bound = function() {
  if (!(this instanceof bound)) return func.apply(context, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
  ctor.prototype = func.prototype;
  var self = new ctor;
  ctor.prototype = null;
  var result = func.apply(self, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
  if (Object(result) === result) return result;
  return self;
};
```

I understand that `_.bind` will allow me to bind arguments for a `new` call, but will it have any practical advantage if I only want to use `myObject.handleSomething` as an event handler?

Is it possible to write something similar to `_.bindAll` using `$.proxy`? E.g.

```
$.proxyAll = function (obj) {
    for (var attr in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr) && $.isFunction(obj[attr])) {
        obj[attr] = $.proxy(obj[attr], obj);
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Comment: Looks like you are having context issues upon getting your event handled by `myObject.handleSomething` so you are trying to bind the context to the handler, am I right? if so, why not just passing the context as part of your event data?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but that doesn't even make sense (how would I even go about getting the `myObject` context into the event data?).  What I need is `Object.bind()`, but because of IE I need to use a library. There is a rather large performance difference between underscore.js and jQuery, where jQuery is much faster. The first part of my question is whether this speed difference is due to lack of generality, and the second part of my question is whether `_.bindAll()` is directly implementable from `jQuery.proxy()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're measuring the performance you care about?

Seems your test case is measuring the performance of binding the function, whereas this test case measures the performance of the bound function:
http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy/38

You should only be binding functions a finite (and relatively small) number of times, so performance wouldn't really matter.  It was a surprise to me, but measuring the performance of the bound function seems to flip the results.

Also, note that your original test results varied across browsers.

Comment: Good catch.  (The benchmark wasn't mine, but one I found links to when researching bind implementations).  I've ran the benchmark with a collection of browsers I have available, and added version 39 where I also added native bind.

Comment: Nice addition.  Thanks!  I didn't know there was a native bind.